# Attaching contextMenu to flot graph points

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, flot

I am trying to attach the jQuery plugin contextMenu to the points in a flot graph. I have the right click context menu working using the following code:

```
$(".chart").bind("plotclick").contextMenu('myMenu1', {
    bindings: {
      'delete': function(t) {

                 // Do stuff when delete is clicked

      }
    }
});
```

With the above, if I right click on any of the points on the graph a little menu pops up with "DELETE" in it.

However I need access to the data provided by flot about the point that was clicked. Normally the `plotclick` function would look like this:

```
$(".chart").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {

    // In here I can see details about the point that was clicked by looking at event, pos and item

})
```

So my question is, how do I pass the `event, pos, item` variables through to the delete function of the contextMenu in my first code above? Is what I'm doing even the right way to attach the contextMenu?

Thanks

Comment: Can you produce a jsFiddle of what you have so far?  I started working on it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4FCqr/, but can't quite get a working sample.

Comment: @Mark Made a few tweaks to get the fiddle working up to where I am at the moment. I had to copy the context plugin directly in to the JavaScript window, the linked file just wasn't working. http://jsfiddle.net/4FCqr/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about your bind the context menu generically to the plot container div and then use the `plothover` event to keep track of whether or not you are "over" a point? If you aren't over a point, you suppress the pop-up, if you are over one you get the point information from a global-scoped variable.

```
 $("#placeholder").contextMenu('myMenu1', {
    onContextMenu: function(e) {
        if (somePoint) return true;
        else return false;
    },

    bindings: {
      'delete': function(t) {
        alert(lastPoint.series.label);    
      }
    }
});

var somePoint = null, lastPoint = null;
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item){
        somePoint = item;
    }else{
        lastPoint = somePoint;
        somePoint = null;   
    }
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4FCqr/2/).

BTW, the reason my original fiddle didn't work, was I had the wrong jquery context menu.  I thought you were using this [one](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) not this [one](http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/).

Comment: My bad, I should have been more specific. This is a clever solution, but it doesn't always fire the delete function. I am not sure what the pattern is, but definitely from a fresh page load, the first right click and "delete" click fires the alert, if I then right click the same point and click "delete" it doesn't fire the alert. It was also randomly not firing the alert clicking between different line points..

Comment: Found the pattern. If I right click the point, then move the mouse somewhere else over graph, then go back and click delete nothing happens. Must be because you are setting somePoint to null when I hover over nothing after right clicking...

Comment: I have fixed the problem (I think) with the following changes http://jsfiddle.net/4FCqr/3/ what do you think?